# How to connect ontology and web application

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, jena, semantic-web, ontology

I'm working on a project, within which we are using semantic web technologies and creating web application allows user to get recommendation in order to take right decision ( won't get into the details).
For me and my team its a first experience to work with ontology.
We've already created ontology (have rdf and owl formatted files)(We are using eclipse to keep them).
Separately, we've created web application. My question how to connect web page and owl, rdf formatted data,  more precisely, how to ensure input through webpage to dataset and get output on page.
I've found some  info( on old forums), that its easyrdf which can be used as embedded in php script. But not clear.
Based on youtube tutorials, I've downloaded jena fuseki and don't know what is the next step.

I would be glad to get any advice, suggestion :)

Comment: good point, the fuseki documentation is completely missing a example how to transfer your Jena Style OntModel within a transaction to Fuseki and back.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, there is no a single way to do this.

I usually set up some back-end application in order to pre-process this kind of information (build SPARQL queries, execute them and parse the results) and then return to the front in some way understandable by that side.

So, you could have all your data in RDF format store, for example, in a TDF exposed by Fuseki and interact with that data with some back-end, aimed to consume, update and parse the results you could find there.

That's my advice, hope could be useful for you.

Good luck!